# Wordpress Gallery - link to original file

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery

I'm having a bit of trouble with the Wordpress Gallery. When looking at the gallery on the front-end page the links to the original file are set to the 300 pixel wide version - rather than the original file. I would like it to go to the original image which could be 1280 x 720 for example.

When setting up the gallery there is no option for the size of image to link to like there is for individual images. I can only choose number of columns, and whether to link to media file, or attachment page.

I'm using the `twentyfourteen` theme.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is no settings in wordpress, to achieve this. You will have to go into coding.

I looked into the code of twentyfourteen theme. The theme has defined a filter 'twentyfourteen_attachment_size' in functions.php file. We can make use of it to change the size. 
Add following code in your functions.php file, and it should work for you.

```
add_filter('twentyfourteen_attachment_size','change_size');
function change_size($size)
{
    $size = 'full'; //'full' parameter will display the image in its original size. 
    return $size;
}
```